# How to declare a reactive firebase user using getx package

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-getx

I want to declare a FirebaseUser (from the firebase_auth package), in a reactive way.

`Rx<FirebaseUser> firebaseUser = Rx<FirebaseUser>();`

But `Rx<FirebaseUser>()` give me the error

"1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found".

Any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a null safety version of GetX?

If so, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
Rxn<User> firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
```